# HDInsight Cores Quota increase

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, quota

I have two different HDInsight deployments that I need to deploy. One of the HDInsight deployments uses the D12_v2 VM type and the second HDInishgt deployment uses the DS3_v2 VM type.

Although both the VM types use the same number of cores, would the deployments work if I just request a quota increase of the Dv2-series type? Do note that, at a time, only a single deployment will exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although both the VM types use the same number of cores, would the
> deployments work if I just request a quota increase of the Dv2-series
> type?

No, it won't work that way as both are of different VM series i.e. `Dv2` and `DSv2`. So , even if they are using same cores , deployment will fail in that region if you don't have sufficient quota to allocate in your subscription for both of the VM series as it depends on your total Vcpu's available for that region.

You can refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series) for the VM series specifications.

So , as per your requirement ,You have to create the quota request for both the series in the particular region .

**Reference for Quota limits of VM:**

[Request an increase in vCPU quota limits per Azure VM series - Azure supportability | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/per-vm-quota-requests)

**Reference for Quota limits of HDInsights:**

[CPU Core quota increase request - Azure HDInsight | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/quota-increase-request)

Comment: The doc link in your answer indicates the user should ask for Compute quota, which is not accurate for HDInsight. They need to request HDInsight specific quota in the drop down when they create a support request.

Comment: Hello @MimiGentz,Yes you are correct , but for the clarification of the ask of 2 vm series i have added that link. will add the hdinsights quota rest link as well. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You should include both VMs in your request.

Please refer to the following document which provides info about requesting a quota increase for HDInsight. You need to be sure to ask for HDInsight quota, and not regular Compute-VM quota. In the text box entry, you state which VMs you need and they will process the request accordingly.

[Requesting quota increases for Azure HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/quota-increase-request)